# php variable is getting overwritten

Tags: php

Hi I am facing a problem that $state has the value '-' insted of 'created'. The function looks like this:

```
private function create() {
        $this->$state = 'created';
        $this->$dateCreated = date('d/m/y');
        $this->$dateAssigned = '-';
        $this->$assigner = '-';
        $this->$dateFinished = '-';
        var_dump($this->$state);
    }
```

so as said above var_dump($this->$state) returns '-' instead of 'created'

all my variables are private

```
class Task {
    private $id;
    private $priority;
    private $priorityColor;
    private $title;
    private $state;
    private $dateCreated;
    private $dateAssigned;
    private $assigner;
    private $dateFinished;
    private $description;
```

What is the problem in this case, because in the constructor call I have a similar case with $id but it returns the correct value

```
    public function __construct($id, $priority, $title, $description) {
        $this->$id = $id;
        $this->$priority = $priority;
        $this->$title = $title;
        $this->$description = $description;
        $this->create();
        var_dump($this->$id);
    }
```

First I did it without the $this but then $state is NULL outside of the function

Comment: it should be `$this->id` etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the properties of the object, you shouldn't put `$` before the property's name

```
// Instead of
$this->$state = 'created';

// Do
$this->state = 'created'; // Notice that there is no "$" after the arrow "->"

// Same for the other properties.
// ...
```

---

`$this->$state` has another meaning. Here `$state` is not the property but rather its content. Check this:

```
public function myMethod() {
    $statePropertyName = 'state';
    $this->$statePropertyName = 'created';

    // The two lines above are equivalent to doing:
    $this->state = 'created';
}
```

[More info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)